# Cookie hacking: is it possible to edit them manually?

Tags: http, cookies, https, setcookie

I think this is not the first time someone askes this question. But I couldn't get a clear answer.

Is it possible to "hack" a cookie? For example, If someone is logged in, I create an 'user id' cookie, with value 'usr01301', and this is a reference to that user. If this user is loading the webpage, the website will check for cookies. If a 'user id' is available, the user will login with the account connected to the user id.

But, is someone able to write this cookie manually? Or change it to another ID? To be able to login with this cookie.

Comment: Yes that possible by doing things like manipulating HTTP requests, but any good website will use more sophisticated methods than just the user's name to do validation.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

[Session Hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) is a very real thing, and it is easy to exploit on any website that does not have good security systems in place.  Using a username in a cookie is a **really, really bad idea**.

There are browser plugins that make it easy to [edit cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg), but you can even do it using the developer console that ships with many browsers.

For that matter, you don't need a browser at all.  `wget` can perform [http requests with cookies](https://www.apharmony.com/software-sagacity/2014/10/using-wget-with-cookies/#:%7E:text=Using%20Wget%20with%20Cookies.%20One%20of%20the%20powerful,web%20and%20save%20them%20to%20the%20local%20disk.) from the command line.

Comment: Oh that's a really bad thing. I am new in to auth, so just figuring a lot of things out, and learn things. 

What could be a good way to write a cookie, but also authorize another way to make sure someone hasn't edit the cookie?

Comment: @WoutervanStralen look at the Session Hijacking Wekipedia page.  It has a section on "Prevention".  That's a good overview of what topics to look into.  In short: security is hard, which is why it's usually better to use a framework that has taken those aspects into account by (hopefully) more experienced developers.

Answer (score 0):

predictable cookies are a bad idea. with that, anyone can predict cookie for any user existed on that website. and manually edit also possible ad there are lot of tools available o internet to do it autometically.
https://bugarena.com/single/Y7A7WOZ1520